# On button click, check unknown sources from settings

Tags: java, android

i would like to know, is there a possibility that on button click to check the allow installation from unknown sources , so i want that the user could check that from my app, thanks in advance

Comment: You can direct the user to the related settings page, but not check it directly, unless device is rooted.

Comment: so i can't check it directly, there isn't a solution to check it?

Comment: There is a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026554/turn-on-unknown-sources-setting-programatically), but works on rooted devices. On non-rooted devices, it won't work