# Allow "unknown sources" in app

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to allow "unknown sources" with code?

Now i have only a popup that send users in security settings but they should allow manually. I'm thinking to allow it with a popup with a check box, can i access it?

Comment: I don't believe so, it is for security, and limits apps to the play store, it wouldn't really be safe to allow it automatically.

Comment: Yes. Even it needs root access to the device. Better not to use since it could be vulnerable to malicious apps.

Answer (score 0):

You Can't if you try to write settings you would get an exception

see this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19027097/3151567)